# C# beginner has a problem with class attributes

Tags: c#

I am a C# beginner and and I've been working on object-orientation for the past few days.
That is why please excuse my if the question is dumb.

I wrote 2 attributes for a class. Can anyone say to me where is the difference between the first and the second?

```
public class house
{
    private int Height;
    public int _Height
    {
        get { return Height; }
    }

    public int height { get; }
}
```

Is there a difference between?

Comment: They are almost identical but not quite. In the 2nd example, the compiler will create a backing field, but it will be readonly. In the 1st example, your field is not readonly. Also, all your naming conventions are wrong.

Comment: It would be usual to use the underscore for the private member.

Comment: The correct C# term for OOP attributes is "property". First property is implemented manually. Second is auto-implemented.

Comment: Indeed; don't call them attributes- we use that for something else

Answer (score 6):

C# knows *fields* and *properties*. A field stores data, a property accesses it. In the basic form, this looks as follows:

```cs
public class House
{
    private int _height; // a field storing an integer
    public int Height // A property that can be used to access the _height field
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
        set
        {
            _height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is, for an outside viewer (almost) equivalent to:

```cs
public class House
{
    public int Height; // a public field storing an integer
}
```

but this is discouraged, because fields should not be public. If you want to change something inside your class later, that gets more difficult.

The property has different advantages, one of them being that you can debug when the value gets changed, or you can verify that the value is in range (e.g that no one is setting a negative height). You can also leave away the setter, which allows the users of the class to only read the field, but not set it.

Since properties are so common in C#, the following abbreviation is allowed:

```cs
public class House
{
    public int Height // An auto-implemented property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

These properties are called auto-implemented. Again, for an outsider, this looks exactly the same and the compiler actually converts this to exactly the same code as the first example above. The only difference is that you cannot directly access the field. And you cannot add verification code with this syntax.

So basically, the three variants achieve almost the same result and it is mostly a matter of taste which one to use. By convention, the last variant is mostly used if no verification needs to be done, otherwise variant 1.

Per comment, here is an example with verification:

```cs
public class House
{
    private int _height; // a field storing an integer
    public int Height // A property that can be used to access the _height field
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                 throw new InvalidOperationException("The height of a house cannot be less than 0");
            }
            _height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! Just a suggestion, perhaps an example of what a verification might be would help OP understand why pick the [much more verbose] variant 1?

Comment: @CoolBots Like this?

Comment: Yep! +1, thank you!

Comment: Well, it knows [Attribute]s too.. 

Comment: And if you want the short short form, `record House(int Height)`